# What happens if I fail the G2 road test with 2+ years of foreign experience?

Tags: driving-license, canada, ontario

With 2+ years of foreign driving experience, new residents of Ontario with licenses ineligible for direct exchange (such as a license from The Netherlands), can skip the graduated licensing system and take the G2 road test directly.  For example, see [exchange foreign drivers license](https://www.ontario.ca/driving-and-roads/exchange-foreign-drivers-licence).

I recall reading or hearing that if one under these circumstances *fails* the G2 road test, then the credited foreign driving experience is annulled and one has to go through the full graduated system, thus forcing one to wait at least 20 months to take the G2 road test again.  However, I'm unable to verify this information now.

What happens if one fails the G2 road test (G2 exit test) with credited foreign driving experience?  Can one take the test again soon after, or must one indeed go through the full graduated system?

Answer (score 2):

The process depends on where your license is from. As your links says, if your license is from certain countries you an simply exchange it for an Ontario license. Netherlands is not on the list.

[This page documents the process for other countries](http://www.mto.gov.on.ca/english/dandv/driver/handbook/section1.12.0.shtml). You exchange your license for a G1 license, granting restricted driving privileges. You are then in the system like an Ontario learner - you need to take the G2 test, or the G test if you have two years driving experience, in specific amounts of time.

Assuming that your G1 license functions in exactly the same way as an Ontario learner driver (which appears to be the case), you have to take the G2 test (or G test) within a certain amount of time. [Failing the G2 test does not invalidate your G1, or prevent you taking the G2 test again](https://www.ontario.ca/driving-and-roads/what-happens-if-i-fail-g1-or-g2-road-test). There are limits on how soon you can retake the test, but I believe it's only a few weeks.

However **if your G1 expires without you having passed the G2, then you will have to begin the process again**. Likewise for the G2. Both of those are valid for five years, so an experienced driver should have no trouble progressing to the next stage in that time.